# Windows 7 AVG and Left 4 Dead

Tags: desktop-computer, avg-antivirus

I have a father who won't allow video games at all. I managed to get a CD version of left 4 dead working perfectly on one laptop, but when I have another with avg, I run into an issue. It immediately blocks it and I don't have administrative privileges. Most l4d players using avg know that it perceived it as a trojan. My dad would not know if I messed up avg. Is there any way I can get left 4 dead working properly?

Comment: My sympathies, but if you don't have the necessary rights to modify AVG's settings or add an exception for the game, attempting to mess it up somehow would most likely create a bigger system-level mess. Not to mention potentially leaving the system completely unprotected and vulnerable, which is something to certainly be concerned about even if your father doesn't notice.

Comment: I understand the risk and I do have another antivirus that does not see it as a Trojan. I have worked with this sort of thing before and I am prepared for any ramifications involved. I also have PC backups in the case that it truly does get bad

Comment: You mean you have another AV installed and running simultaneously? Otherwise what good will it do since you can't even remove AVG and install the other one instead if you lack admin rights?

Comment: I already have a second one installed (by my dad, I might add)

Comment: Having multiple real-time scanners is a bad idea. Maybe you can convince him to uninstall AVG so that hopefully the other AV will co-exist with the game better.

Comment: Not going to happen, the two have already been working well together for a while, and my dad loves avg and hates uninstalling programs.

Comment: Ok then, hopefully you can get someone to tell you how to mess up AVG, or preferably do what you want without messing it up.

Comment: I would too but its my only choice.